# Hive Join - based on multiple conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, join, presto, amazon-athena

In one of my table which contains date and event columns.

```
select * from event
```

it returns,

```
date event
2016-03-20 Launch
2016-03-20 delete
2016-03-20 Launch
2016-03-20 launch
2016-03-19 delete
2016-03-19 stop
```

I want the result as using group by date

```
date | count(Luanch) | count(delete) | count(stop)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      date
           ,count(case when event = 'Launch' then 1 end) as count_Launch
           ,count(case when event = 'delete' then 1 end) as count_delete
           ,count(case when event = 'stop'   then 1 end) as count_stop

from        event

group by    date
;
```

---

```
    date    | count_Launch | count_delete | count_stop
------------+--------------+--------------+-------------
 2016-03-19 |      0       |      1       |    1
 2016-03-20 |      2       |      1       |    0
```

Comment: It throws, Queries of this type are not supported ,

any other solutions?

Comment: ,count(case event when 'launch' then 1 end  ) as Launch, This worked in athena

Comment: It does not make any sense. You were not able to qualify a column name using `"`?

Comment: Dudu, I'm new to this, I don't know why its not working in Athena, let me check why.